# Mac 17" stuck in reboot loop

Tags: restart

I turn on my mac to a grey screen then the apple logo appears then the log in I put in my password then I see my account pic with a loading bar below it then the screen goes grey shuts off and does the same thing I have have tried safe mode and recovery mode the macOS Sierra. the mac is 17inch

Comment: We're missing some details here like Mac Model (iMac or Macbook Pro) what version of the OS are you running?  Have you tried Verbose Mode (Cmd-V while turning on)?  Remember, we're not there to look over your shoulder so the more relevant details the better.

Comment: The os version is yosimite when I try verbose mode so far the screen appears as it should black with white text then the screen goes conpletely grey

Comment: Couple things to do...while booting in Verbose mode, see if there are any errors that appear; use a cell phone camera to catch everything.  Secondly, run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.

Comment: I video taped the verbose mode and there was no error them the screen turned grey and when I turn it on holding d the screen turns on grey and stays grey

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Many times the messages that get output *before* the Mac crashes/reboots/etc. can give a clue as to what's happening.  Also did your run AHT?

Comment: When I got the hardware testing screen up it ran and said there were no problems

Comment: Did you run the extended tests?